# Cloud: can i use the same account for 2 computers with different data

Tags: ubuntu-one, cloud

i have two computers, a laptop and a desktop, i use my laptop for study and tower for movies and songs, so i have different data on either computers, can i use the same 'cloud' account for both computers and still be able to sustain my current data on both computers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are backing up on Ubuntu-One is shared between the two computers, things are just fine. Just place the shared stuff under the Ubuntu-One directory.

If you have different things being backed up and their sum fits within your Ubuntu-One storage limit, make two different subdirectories under the Ubuntu-One dir and use the correct one from each machine.

Does that cover your question? or, are you asking something different?

Comment: yep, that has resolved my question, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can have several different folders synchronized, independent of the Ubuntu One-folder. The Ubuntu One-folder is automatically synced between all your computers. If you add another synced folder, then you will be notified on other computers, asking if you want to sync it. So you can sync a folder between all your laptops, but not your desktop, for instance. You can select this from the Ubuntu One Control panel in the "Cloud folders" page.